# Unterschied zwischen "wissen um.. ", "wissen von.." und "wissen über.."

Tags: meaning, verb, phrase

Ich habe immer die Ausdrucksformen *wissen von..* oder *wissen über..* verwendet, trotzdem habe ich zufällig den folgenden Satz aus der Serie "[The Exorcist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5368542/)" gehört -ehrlich gesagt habe ich gelesen, weil die Serie mit Untertitel auf Deutsch ist- :

> Die Welt weiß nicht um euch

Ich verstehe die Bedeutung, in diesem Fall übersetze ich in Italienisch und alles läuft gut, allerdings -manchmal benötige ich Sätze zu bilden und nicht immer zu übersetzen- begreife ich nicht, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen den drei Ausdrucksformen gibt oder nicht, und wenn schon, kann mir jemand erklären? Außerdem, ist die Ausdruck *wissen über..* umgangssprachlich?

PS= Ist es korrekt *zwischen den drei Ausdrucksformen* zu schreiben?

Answer (score 3):

"Ich weiß über das Thema" is not a phrasing that Germans use. We do use "Ich weiß über das Thema *Bescheid*", though.

"Ich weiß von ihm" is not unusual, if it is used correctly, as in: "Ich weiß von ihm, dass (er Russisch gelernt hat)"="I know (about him) that he studied Russian" or "Das weiß ich von ihm"="I know this from him".

If you wish to say "I know him", you must say "Ich kenne ihn" instead. "Ich weiß *nichts* von ihm" is usual, though, and also: "Ich weiß von nichts"="I don't know a thing (about sth./so.)".

"Ich weiß um die Bedeutung" is slightly archaic, but understandable. It is often used with a nominal phrase (hence "Bedeutung" would be followed by another noun construction) as in "Ich weiß um die Bedeutung des Fischfangs für diese Region" and means "I am aware of the meaning/importance of sth/.so."

"Zwischen den drei Formen" is a perfectly fine thing to say. (Pedants might object that you should use "Unterschied*e*", since there is only one difference between two things, but three differences between three...)

Answer (score 3):

> wissen um

Is used to say that you know that something or someone exists. The form is often used in religious texts and literature while in "modern German" you typically use "wissen von" (see below) or a combination with the verb "geben" instead:

> Literature form: Nicht einmal der Händler **wusste um** das Geld.
>
> "Modern" German 1: Nicht einmal der Händler **wusste, dass** es das Geld **gab**.
>
> "Modern" German 2: Nicht einmal der Händler **wusste von** dem Geld.

---

> wissen über

do not say that you know that something exists but that you have knowledge about something:

> Er weiß sehr viel **über** Italien.

Means that someone has a lot of knowledge about Italy.

---

> wissen von

... is sometimes used instead of "wissen über":

> Was weißt du **von** Italien?

(However I think that this form is not "official German" but I'm not sure.)

... and sometimes used instead of "wissen um":

> Weißt du **von** dem Geld?

A third possibility is that the "von" in "wissen von" refers to the source of information:

> Das weiß ich **von** Herrn Mustermann.
>
> Das weiß ich **von** dem Vortrag.

Means:

> I know this because Mr. Mustermann told me.
>
> I know this because I was informed on the presentation.

Note: If you have information from a book or from the school you don't say "**vom** Buch" ("vom" is equal to "von dem") but "**aus** dem Buch" or "**aus** der Schule".